# How to observe off-diagonal long range order in superfluid?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, superconductivity, bose-einstein-condensate, superfluidity

off-diagonal long range order in superfluid is an effect that the matrix element of the single particle's density matrix remains finite in the long distance limit.

My question is: how to prove this experimentally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should first be noted that Off-Diagonal Long-Range Order (ODLRO) and superfluidity do no necessarily go hand in hand. ODLRO is associated with a Bose-Einstein condensed phase (BEC), which usually also behaves as a superfluid and the latter thus inherits the ODLRO property. However, you can have systems that are superfluid but where BEC is not possible (and hence lack *true* ODLRO, but can display some sort of *quasi*-ODLRO) such as the [BKT phase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosterlitz%E2%80%93Thouless_transition).

So anyway. Following the above, let's rephrase your question to *How to observe off-diagonal long range order in a Bose-Einstein condensate?*

Let's look at the asymptotic behaviour of the off-diagonal one-body density matrix, used in the Penrose-Onsager criterion as a rigorous definition for a BEC. In the first quantisation formalism, this is defined as:
\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
n^{(1)}(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{r}') = \sum_i n_i\, \psi_i^\ast(\mathbf{r}) \psi_i(\mathbf{r}') \\ = n_0\,\phi_0(\mathbf{r})^\ast \phi_0(\mathbf{r}')+ \sum_{i\neq 0} n_i\, \psi_i(\mathbf{r})^\ast \psi_i(\mathbf{r}) \\ = n_0\, \phi_0(\mathbf{r})^\ast \phi_0(\mathbf{r}')+ \sum_{i\neq 0} n_i\, \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\mathrm{i}}{\hbar}\mathbf{p}\cdot(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}')}, 
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}
where in the last term a special case of free particles was assumed, to express them as plane waves. $n_0$ is the density of atoms in the $0$ state (ground state), which we have taken out of the sum $\sum_i$ for reasons below. 
 At increasing separation, this tends to a constant value because the contributions of $\mathbf{p} \neq 0$ average out:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{|\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}'| \rightarrow \infty} n^{(1)}(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{r}')\rightarrow n_0 \neq 0.
\end{equation}
This is exactly the definition of *Off-Diagonal* (because of the $\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{r}'$) *Long-Range* (because of the limit $|\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}'| \rightarrow \infty$) *order*, ODLRO.

To confirm this experimentally, then, you have to devise an experiment where you can see whether or not phase coherence is preserved over 'long distances'. One such experiment is reported [here](https://www.nature.com/articles/35003132) (plot shown below). What is plotted is the visibility of the fringes in a matter-wave interference pattern as a function of the spatial extent of the atomic cloud (in this sense, $z$ larger than the inteatomic spacing is considered 'large distances'). For a thermal state, this decays to zero within the thermal de Broglie wavelength, whereas for a BEC it stays constant owing to the presence of off-diagonal long-range order (the actual constant is related to $n_0$).
[image]